# Software Centre?

Tags: software-center

I just now installed Ubuntu 16.04. I know that there is supposed to be a new software centre, but I'm still getting the old one? I've tried running they software updater but it says I'm up to date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove Ubuntu Software Center manually and if not already installed, install Ubuntu Software instead. Open terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and execute the following commands:
`sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software`

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it's the old one. They have the same icon, but the old one is called `Ubuntu Software Center`, while the new one is called `Ubuntu Software`.

If you have the old one, you'll see something like this:
[image]

GNOME Software (the new one) looks like:
[image]

If this is a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04, there should be no way you have the old Software Center. Upgrading to 16.04 from an older version of Ubuntu will leave you with both Software Centers.